# 'It' referring to a totality of more than just one entity

Tags: pronouns

> "My father loved to paint. He was a very accomplished amateur painter.
>   Oils-he painted pictures of abandoned mills, and of barns, and of
>   people and sailboats and lighthouses. All of it was real. All of it he
>   saw around New London." ('Chevrolet, Summers, Dairy Queen Nights' by
>   Bob Greene: http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1994-02-13/features/9402130068_1_tom-condon-new-york-golf)

Hello, I was just wondering why 'all of them were ...' and 'all of them he saw ...' couldn't be used. I know 'it' refers to a totality of 'abandoned mills,' 'barns,' 'people,' 'sailboats,' and 'lighthouses.' But can't just 'them' be used to look at the 'abandoned mills,' 'barns,' etc.?

Comment: Here, "it" refers to *all of my father's art*, in total, as a mass noun, as opposed to a collection of discrete paintings (his works are not limited to those enumerated in the paragraph). Because it's taken as a unitary whole, we use *is* instead of *are*.

Comment: So 'it' refers to more than just those enumerated there? If it were 'them,' it would only refer to the things listed there?

Comment: @Ssamy, if he had said "*All of them were real*", that would set up the antecedent of *them* as the actual, physical, *barns*, *mills*, *bridges*, and so on (whether enumerated or not). If he had said "*All of them were realistic*", the referent would again be the *paintings* (individually, as count nouns, whether or not previously enumerated), as opposed to his father's work in whole. Make sense?

Comment: So 'all of them' refers to those not just enumerated there but also not enumerated of the objects or his father's pictures. Correct?

Comment: In this context, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

I read the sentence "All of it was real" as being equivalent to "All of the stuff he painted was real," where *stuff* is a singular-form replacement for *subjects*. The speaker could have put it this way:

> He painted pictures of abandoned mills, and of barns, and of people and sailboats and lighthouses. All of the subjects were real. All of them he saw around New London.

Or he could have clarified the first "it" in his actual wording by using this wording instead:

> He painted pictures of abandoned mills, and of barns, and of people and sailboats and lighthouses. All of the stuff [or *subject matter*] he painted was real. All of it he saw around New London.

In spoken English, the shift from an understood plural to an understood singular sometimes occurs without fanfare and (usually) without a great deal of confusion on the hearer's part. But presented with a transcript of such a conversation, a reader may struggle a bit to justify what perhaps seemed at the time that it was spoken to be a perfectly natural shift.

Dan Bron's interpretation of "it" as meaning "my father's art" (in the comments beneath the OP's question) is not unreasonable—especially with regard to the sentence "All of it was real," where the sentence might be interpreted as carrying the sense "all of my father's art reflected reality." But if we understand the first "it" to refer to "my father's art," it seems to me that we have to find another referent for the "it" in the follow-up sentence, "All of it he saw around New London." There, "it" evidently refers not to his art per se but to "the inspiration for his art" or to "this reality" (as implied in the previous sentence).

As I said, the "my father's art" interpretation is defensible, but it takes rather more effort to explain the two instances of "it" in accordance with that interpretation than in accordance with the "stuff he painted" interpretation.